# Querying from AD - NO_OBJECT

Tags: active-directory, comexception

My AD entry has the property `msExchAddressBookPolicyLink` with the value `CN=ABL_Sub,CN=AddressBook Mailbox Policies,CN=MyExchange,CN=Microsoft Exchange,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=intra,DC=contoso,DC=com`.

This value I put into variable abpLink (I checked in VisualStudio Debugger), then using

```
if(abp!=null) {
    DirectoryEntry abpEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://"+abpLink);
```

At that point, abpEntry has raised a COMException, and when looking into the returned Properties, I find the error "problem 2001: NO_OBJECT".

(The ABL_Sub Address Book Policy does still exist, I did not delete it in Exchange.)

How so?

Comment: Does the security context you're running as have access to read that object? By default nobody does.

Comment: Then how will I be able to filter the GAL down to what a single person is allowed to see?

Comment: Get your account added to the Exchange View-Only group in Active Directory and you should have access to read that object.